# How to freeze Inception-ResNet-v2 using Tensorflow checkpoint and TF Python programs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, graph, resnet

How can a pretrained/frozen graph be made for Inception-ResNet-v2 using Tensorflow's Python programs and Tensorflow's checkpoint file (downloaded from [here](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.tar.gz))?

Below shows what I tried, but `freeze_graph.py` doesn't seem to find the variables.

Is there another step missing?

Are the variable names in the graph and in the checkpoint incompatible?

```bash
$ python3 $TENSORFLOW_HOME/models/research/slim/export_inference_graph.py \
--modal_name inception_resnet_v2 \
--output_file /tmp/inception_resnet_v2.pb

2018-01-08 02:35:11.819267: I tensorflow/core/platform/s3/aws_logging.cc:53] Initializing Curl library
/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.

$ python3 $TENSORFLOW_HOME/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py \
--input_graph /tmp/inception_resnet_v2.pb \
--input_checkpoint /tmp/inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt \
--output_graph /tmp/inception_resnet_v2-frozen_graph.pb \
--input_binary true \
--output_node_names 'InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1'

2018-01-08 02:36:23.083874: I tensorflow/core/platform/s3/aws_logging.cc:53] Initializing Curl library
/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/src/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 350, in <module>
    app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/home/rick/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/usr/local/src/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 249, in main
    FLAGS.saved_model_tags)
  File "/usr/local/src/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 239, in freeze_graph
    input_meta_graph_def, input_saved_model_dir, saved_model_tags.split(","))
  File "/usr/local/src/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py", line 127, in freeze_graph_with_def_protos
    saver = saver_lib.Saver(var_list=var_list)
  File "/home/rick/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1288, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/home/rick/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1297, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "/home/rick/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1322, in _build
    raise ValueError("No variables to save")
ValueError: No variables to save
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using V2, but in your command you specified `--output_node_names 'InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1'`. My guess is that the `InceptionV3` should be `InceptionV2`?

By the way, I never use `freeze_graph` to export frozen graph successfully. Another approach is to use [export_inference_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py). The instruction can be find in [Exporting a trained model for inference](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/exporting_models.md).

Finally, if you have already exported `inception_resnet_v2.pb` in your first step (btw, is `--modal_name` a typo of `--model_name`?), why bother to export it again to `inception_resnet_v2-frozen_graph.pb`?